# Javascript won't run on IE without Debugger (F12)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging, dynamics-crm

I am working on a MSCRM page and it loads a simple Javascript with two methods only. One method to load the external Javascript and another method to call that external method and write the result on MSCRM page. These are the codes

```
function addJavascript(jsname, pos) {
    var th = document.getElementsByTagName(pos)[0];
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    s.setAttribute('src', jsname);
    th.appendChild(s);
}

addJavascript('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true&key=xxxxxxx', 'body');

function getLatLang() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_line1").getValue() + "," + Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_city").getValue();
    if (address != '') {
        geocoder.geocode({ "address": address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_latitude").setValue(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_longitude").setValue(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                return;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

They are working properly but only if I run it in debug (IE F12) or if I un-check "Disable script debugging" In IE advanced options which I really don't want to do. I read about the error being caused by calling `console.log()` method of which you can see from above snippet not being called at all.

So in short, how do I get the javascript functions to work without the debugger?

Any pointer is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you cached with an older file that has a console.log line in it? Clear the cache and see if it magically works.

Comment: No such magic ;[ cache was cleared and as explained, console.log was never called. Thanks for the input anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the problem is caused by console.log by trying to create it when it's not available. Add this before your code:

```
var console = console || {};
console.log = console.log || function () {};
```

If it works, you may be missing a required include for the maps script.

Comment: Tried to add that as you instructed and still not working. Thanks for the comment though